# Why am I getting redefinition errors even though I have guards in my header file

Tags: c++, header

I have 2 files so far DoubleNode.hpp and DoubleNode.cpp. When I try to run the program I get redefinition errors and a warning that says extra tokens at the end of #include directive. I am confused because I have guards in my header file and I thought they were suppose to prevent redefinition problems.

here is my header file DoubleNode.hpp:

```
#ifndef DOUBLE_NODE_
#define DOUBLE_NODE_

template <class ItemType> //Reminder this is a template class, implement the .cpp accordingly
class DoubleNode
{
public:
    DoubleNode();                                                                                                                     //default constructor, sets next_ and prev_ to nullptr
    DoubleNode(const ItemType &anItem, DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr = nullptr, DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr = nullptr); //Parameterized Constructor, sets item_ to anItem, next_ to nextNodePtr, prev_ to previousNodePtr
    void setItem(const ItemType &anItem);                                                                                             //sets item_ equal to anItem parameter
    void setPrevious(DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr);                                                                          //sets prev_ equal to previousNodePtr parameter
    void setNext(DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr);                                                                                  //sets next_ equal to nextNodePtr parameter

    ItemType getItem() const;                  //returns item_
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getNext() const;     //returns next_
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *getPrevious() const; //returns prev_

private:
    ItemType item_;              //actual content of your node
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *next_; //pointer to the node that is after this node
    DoubleNode<ItemType> *prev_; //pointer to the node that is before this node
};

#include "DoubleNode.cpp" 
#endif
```

here is my implementation file DoubleNode.cpp:

```
#include "DoubleNode.hpp";

/* Default Constructor */
template <class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>::DoubleNode() : next_{nullptr}, prev_{nullptr}
{
}

/* Parameterized Constructor */
template <class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>::DoubleNode(const ItemType &anItem, DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr, DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr) : item_{anItem}, next_{nextNodePtr}, prev_{previousNodePtr}
{
}

/* Setter: item_ */
template <class ItemType>
void DoubleNode<ItemType>::setItem(const ItemType &anItem)
{
    item_ = anItem;
}

/* Setter: prev_ */
template <class ItemType>
void DoubleNode<ItemType>::setPrevious(DoubleNode<ItemType> *previousNodePtr)
{
    prev_ = previousNodePtr;
}

/* Setter: next_ */
template <class ItemType>
void DoubleNode<ItemType>::setNext(DoubleNode<ItemType> *nextNodePtr)
{
    next_ = nextNodePtr;
}

/* Accessor: item_ */
template <class ItemType>
ItemType DoubleNode<ItemType>::getItem() const
{
    return item_;
}

/* Accessor: next_ */
template <class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType> *DoubleNode<ItemType>::getNext() const
{
    return next_;
}

/* Accessor: prev_ */
template <class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType> *DoubleNode<ItemType>::getPrevious() const
{
    return prev_;
}
```

Any help would be aprreciated

Comment: If you choose to implement templates in another file use an extension other than cpp. You also want to avoid the circular include. You know the header is the only place that file should be included so you don't need to try and reinclude the header.

Comment: Don't put a `;` at the end of an `#include` directive.   Your main problem is that the header includes the cpp file, and the cpp file includes the header.   So, if you compile the cpp file, the compiler will see the definitions twice - the include guards prevent including the header twice, but don't prevent the cpp file from including itself.